# How would I write an algorithm to find the greatest jump from number to number in a sequence?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, math, collatz

If your sequence is `4 2 1`, the largest jump is from 4 to 2. If your sequence is `3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1`, the largest jump is from 5 to 16.

I've made an algorithm however I'm not completely sure what I have done wrong (whever I haven't made the loop properly, set my variables correctly, or something else). I'm not sure what I need to set my index, BiggestDiff, or CurrentDiff too. I tried using a while loop to compare each number in my vector but I get zero (I'm assuming because I set BiggestDiff to zero)

If anyone can point me in the right direction, show me an example, or something else, that will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code below

```
int findBiggestDiff(std::vector<int> sequence)
{
  int index = 0;
  int BiggestDiff = 0 ;
  int CurrentDiff = BiggestDiff;
  CurrentDiff = std::abs(sequence[index] - sequence[index + 1]);
  while (index < sequence.size())
  {
    if (CurrentDiff > BiggestDiff)
    {
      BiggestDiff = CurrentDiff;
    }

    return index;
  }
}
```

Comment: Inside your while loop, you aren't calculating `CurrentDiff` … And you're doing a `return` inside it ...

Comment: You also need to *remember* the two numbers that gave you the biggest difference.

Comment: consider accepting an answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    int indexOfBiggestJump = 0;
    int BiggestDiff = 0 ;
    int CurrentDiff = BiggestDiff;

    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.size() - 1; i++) {
        CurrentDiff = std::abs(sequence[i] - sequence[i + 1]);
        if (CurrentDiff > BiggestDiff)
        {
            BiggestDiff = CurrentDiff;
            indexOfBiggestJump = i;
        }
    }
    return indexOfBiggestJump;
}
```

There are several errors in your code.

1. your `return index` literally does nothing, only returns `index` (which will be 0) always.
2. you are not saving the index of the biggest jump anywhere.
3. if you are looking positions `i` and `i + 1`, you must go until `sequence.size() - 1`, otherwise you will look out of the bounds of `sequence`.

Comment: You should explain or annotate how your code resolves the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't recalculating `CurrentDiff` at all. Also, your `return` statement in the in the wrong spot. You can do something like this (not tested)

```
int findLargest( const std::vector<int> &sequence ) {
  if ( sequence.size() < 2 ) return -1; // if there's not at least two elements, there's nothing valid.
  int index = 0;
  int biggestIndex = -1;
  int biggestDiff = -1;

  while (index < sequence.size() - 1) // -1 so that the +1 below doesn't go out of range
  {
    // get the current difference
    int currentDiff = std::abs(sequence[index] - sequence[index + 1]);
    if (currentDiff > biggestDiff)
    {
       // update stats
       biggestIndex = index;
       biggestDiff = currentDiff;
    }
    ++index;
  }
  return biggestIndex
}

int main() {
   //…
   int index = findLargest( sequence );
   if ( index != -1 ) {
       std::cout << "Biggest difference was between " << sequence[index] << " and " << sequence[index+1];
   }
}
```